# Faster alternative to Load function in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, load

I have about 20000 .mat files that I have to load individually.

Each file contains ten (1000 x 1) singles.

The bottle neck in my code is when I have to load these files.

Is there a faster way then the standard 'load' function to get data onto the workspace?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not. Note that in the future, you might be better off saving them in ascii format, or each as a separate variable in a single .mat file.

Comment: Captain Hindsight's answer would be to not design yourself into a situation where you have to load 20000 tiny files.  But if you must do so, and if you have some control over how they're saved, you can also pass the `-v6` flag when you save each `.mat` file.  Then they will be uncompressed—might be faster to load.

Comment: Both comment above make sense (except for the ascii format, avoid that if possible). Depending on the 'randomness' of your data, an uncompressed format might be better indeed, specially for files so small. If you can, you would benefit by doing a one time conversion: load your 20000 files, then save then in one big array (or a few if it makes more sense), but keep the number of file short. Having many files to locate and load individually creates a lot of overhead which no Matlab trick can avoid.

Comment: I'd like to add that, if you are forced to use that many files you might be able to put them into a ramdisk to increase loading speed. For that there should be some ready-to-use tools out there ;)

Comment: Awesome guys. 

I've made a couple of changes... have loaded all relevant memory on to Ram and made a more efficient indexing method. I used -v6, and that helps alot

Thanks for the advice, appreciate it.